# Matlab: finding position of last nonzero digit of a number

Tags: matlab, rounding-error

I have a column vector `pp` filled with numbers, for instance:

```
23.234000
3.1237340
4.4359000
```

I want to find the number of places to the right of the decimal that the smallest nonzero digit in the vector occupies, which would in this case be `6`, because of the `4` in `3.123734`. Then I want to multiply every number in the vector by 10^6, to get rid of all decimals in the vector. I want to do this to eliminate rounding errors. What's the best way to get this done?

Comment: Can you describe in a bit more detail what you mean by eliminate rounding errors? Because it is rounding errors that would make me say that it is impossible to do this. How do you know that `3.1237340` isn't actually `3.12373400000000000009884`?

Comment: I agree with Dan, in float / double representation, any numbers are simply the closest to what the machine is capable of representing. Number of significant figures is really the important factor, multiplying everything by 1.0e6 doesn't really change the precision.

Comment: some examples, why you have to be careful with floating numbers on a binary system are given here: [TMW: Floating-Point numbers] (http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/matlab_prog/floating-point-numbers.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual value may be different from what is actually being *displayed* by MATLAB. For instance, consider the following example:

```
>> x = 1.4 - [0.1; 0.09999999]

x =
   1.3000
   1.3000
```

MATLAB shows both values to be 1.3, but in fact, none of them is:

```
>> x - 1.3

ans =
  -2.2204e-16
   1.0000e-08
```

My suggestion is therefore to decide on a fixed accuracy (say, 6 digits), and then multiply by the corresponding power of 10.